# How to build nested JSON object?

Tags: java, javascript, json, web-applications, servlets

I'm new to JSON and have a Java servlet that gives the following JSON output:

```
{
     "35808": "Huntsville, Alabama",
     "94203": "Sacramento, California",
     "33054": "Miami, Florida",
     "32801": "Orlando, Florida",
     "30301": "Atlanta, Georgia",
     "78717": "Austin, Texas"
}
```

After retrieving the JSON via Javascript I want to create a nested JSON that groups by state, the result should be:

```
 {
     "A": {
         "35808": "Huntsville, Alabama"
     },
     "C": {
         "94203": "Sacramento, California"
     },
     "F": {
         "33054": "Miami, Florida",
         "32801": "Orlando, Florida"
     },
     "G": {
         "30301": "Atlanta, Georgia"
     },
     "T": {
         "78717": "Austin, Texas"
     }
}
```

What is the best way to accomplish this using Javascript preferably? or if Java is used what is the best way?

Thanks,
Jay

Comment: When you put more than one `JSON` object, it is no longer a JSON object it should be a JSON array.

Comment: I've tried using Javascript to build a two-dimensional array that stores the letter {"A", "C", "F", "G", "T"} and the {"zipcode": "city", "state"}, I then used the JSON.stringify(array) function to get a JSON string with no success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do it:

```
var parsedJSON = …;
var byState = {};
for (var prop in parsedJSON) {
    var address = parsedJSON[prop];
    var state = address.split(",")[1] || "";
    var stateKey = state.charAt(0);
    if (! (stateKey in byState))
        byState[stateKey] = {};
    byState[stateKey][prop] = address;
}
console.log(JSON.stringify(byState, null, 4));
```

Comment: Similar to what I was trying to do, Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

This assumes the states are sorted.
http://jsfiddle.net/N23SL/

```
var originalJson = {
     "35808": "Huntsville, Alabama",
     "94203": "Sacramento, California",
     "33054": "Miami, Florida",
     "32801": "Orlando, Florida",
     "30301": "Atlanta, Georgia",
     "78717": "Austin, Texas"
}


var groupMe = function(originalJson)
{
    var grouped = {};
    // loop over each property
    for(var key in originalJson)
    {
        var value = originalJson[key];
        var state=value.split(", ")[1];
        var stateLetter = state[0];

        var letterGroup = grouped[stateLetter];
        if(typeof letterGroup === 'undefined')
        {
            letterGroup = {};
            grouped[stateLetter] = letterGroup;
        }

        letterGroup[key] = value;
    }

    return grouped;

};

var groupedJson = groupMe(originalJson);

console.log(groupedJson);
```